# Android Notification Opens On Existing Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, notifications

I am in trouble with notification intents. I have a service(Service checks for messages and creates notification) which creates notifications. And application has an action bar and via slide menu users can navigate between activities.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJXe6.png

When user clicks notification it opens a new activity on the current activity.(Like an independent new instance). I want to open them in the same instance as if user navigating manually(Like clicking A when on B activity ie)

My current activity launchMode is standard(Although I tried singleTop and singleTask and flags)

Current Notification code :

```
Intent i = null;
i = new Intent(this, MessagesListActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,i, 0);
Builder notificationBuilder  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
notificationBuilder.setContentText(msg);
notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.speech_bubble_orange);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
notificationManager.notify(Constants.UNREADMESSAGESNOTIFICATIONID,notification);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. With this combination new launched activity clears stackback. I also did not change the launchmodes (still standard)

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, you have to tag your activity as single instance, and keep the singleTask

```
android:launchMode= "singleTask" | "singleInstance"
```

in addition, you may have to remove the single top flag from your intent.

Comment: Tried it, not working it still starts activity seperately from the current application. Btw while navigating between activies i kill previous activity because they also open on current activity in default (changing to singleTask/instance does not change this behaviour). I am considering a workaround like killing previous activities on notification click. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I think what you are looking for  is the `TaskStackBuilder`. It allows you to create a backstack to provide proper navigation to the `Activity` being launched by the `PendingIntent`.

See the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html) for more information.